# html2canvas Generates Blank if canvas is NOT added to body

Tags: javascript, ajax, html2canvas

The idea is simple and widely described :
Take a screenshot using html2canvas plugin, then, send the image using Ajax to server .

To do so, I use

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("body"))
    .then(canvas => {

        document.body.appendChild(canvas) // => pay attention to this line

        const b64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace(/.*,/, '');
        theFunctionThatSendB64UsingAjax(b64)
        return;
     })
```

So, this elegant piece of code works pretty fine ! 
It generates a canvas element, attach it to body and then send a base64 format string to the server.

But  I don't want to display the canvas nor the image. So, the obvious is to remove the line :

```
document.body.appendChild(canvas)
```

When I do so, the generated image is always blank.

PS: this issue only happens on Firefox ! it works fine on Chrome

So, is there anybody out there with at least a clue ?! 
Or, an alternative to html2canvas.

And, if matters, the server is running a golang script that store the image in a mongodb .
The server side works fine !

html2canvas version 1.0.0-rc.5 !

EDIT :

This issue does not happens on v0.4 as described in answer below !

EDIT:

I Opened an issue on github:

https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/2254

Comment: I didn't find the reason why it happens, but I found a solution to handle this :

The issue happens when I use html2canvas v 1.0.0-rc.5 ( which is latest today ) .

Just downgrade to v0.4.1 and worked fine ( https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js ) .

I will try other versions to see the latest I can get with no issues !

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.takeScreenShot = function() {
    html2canvas(document.body, {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            const b64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace(/.*,/, '');
            console.log("data:image/png;base64, "+b64  )
            //document.getElementById("test").src="data:image/png;base64, "+b64           
        }
    });
}
```

```css
#target{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background:blue;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
}

button{
    display:block;
    height:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque quis eleifend elit. Donec lectus sem, scelerisque sit amet facilisis quis, gravida a lacus. Nunc at lorem egestas, gravida lorem quis, pulvinar ante. Quisque id tempus libero. Mauris hendrerit nunc risus, ac laoreet lectus gravida et. Nam euismod magna ac enim posuere sagittis. Fusce at egestas enim, eu hendrerit enim.
</div>

<button onclick="takeScreenShot()">to image</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work .... I also already tried to, after send it to server, use                             document.body.removeChild(canvas) ... this only give me a 'blink' and still not works .
And @pc_coder : I edited the question. this issue only happens on firefox !

Comment: It seems to work with a div caught by its it, but not body ... I tried to assign Id to body, but, didn't work. Next try will be to clone body into a div then, srceenshot that div. Back in a minute with results !

Comment: Seems like html2canvas can't work on a cloned element ! back to sketch !

Comment: Check phantom.js also

Comment: When i change to body in updated answer i can get all body's image . What is not working in your code ?

Comment: It happens that I am using htm2canvas v1.0.0-rc.5 which has no onrendered method. 
It has and .then callback. Switch to v0.4 like you used, works fine .... :D

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try this :
https://ekoopmans.github.io/html2pdf.js/

> html2pdf.js converts any web page or element into a printable PDF entirely client-side using html2canvas and jsPDF.

I tried it and i worked well for input form (not range type though).

Comment: This belongs as a comment, because it is a tip and it does not provide a clear answer for the questionner.

Comment: I can't comment because I don't have enough points to post a comment. But thanks, I'll be more careful when I'll be able to post comments.

Comment: No worries, I understand. Until you get enough points to comment tips or ask questions to the questionner, please only provide clear answers in your posts, that way all readers can get a clear answer of what they are searching for.